# Parsing hh:mm:ss[.xxx]

Tags: xml-parsing

I would like to parse the time expression hh:mm:ss.xxx (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) in a .XML file. It should look something like that:

`<condition property="illegal-tc">
    <matches pattern="the_pattern" string="${timeCode}"/>
</condition>`

What I need is the negate of the pattern \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}.

I tried by doing ^[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}]$ but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `[...]` construct matches the set of characters between those `[` and `]`. To get a negative match you need the `(?! ... )` "negative lookahead" construct.

The pattern `^(?!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}).*$` matches anything that is *not* "hh:mm:ss.fff".

Note that a single digit hour, or a fraction of less than 3 digits will still match!

Answer (score 0):

I found out another solution: do the "legal-tc" and negate it in the fail condition with the unless tag like this:

`<condition property="legal-tc">`

```
 <matches pattern="^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}$" string="${timeCode}"/>
```

`</condition>`

`<fail message="Illegal Time Code" unless="legal-tc"/>`